# PrestaShop Sorting multiple fields in category

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, prestashop

I want to sort products in category by default filters (like: position, price...) and by quantity. Products with quantity = 0 must be on the end of the list.

Default query in Category.php (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Category.php#L688)

I'm trying to add quantity to ORDER BY, but results are sorted only by position

```
if ($random === true) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY RAND(), stock.`quantity` DESC LIMIT '.(int)$random_number_products;
} else {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.(!empty($order_by_prefix) ? $order_by_prefix.'.' : '').'`'.bqSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way).', stock.`quantity` DESC
    LIMIT '.(((int)$p - 1) * (int)$n).','.(int)$n;
}
```

I'm trying to change this query by adding subquery for avaliable_stock, but results are the same, sorted only by position

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, real_quantity.*'.(Combination::isFeatureActive() ? ', IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute, 0) AS id_product_attribute,
            product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity' : '').', pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`,
            pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, image_shop.`id_image` id_image,
            il.`legend` as legend, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, cl.`name` AS category_default,
            DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB("'.date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00",
            INTERVAL '.(int)$nb_days_new_product.' DAY)) > 0 AS new, product_shop.price AS orderprice
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
            ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').
        (Combination::isFeatureActive() ? ' LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop
        ON (p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')':'').'
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl
            ON (product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
            AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl
            ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
            AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_shop` image_shop
            ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il
            ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image`
            AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m
            ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` ORDER BY `quantity` DESC) AS real_quantity
            ON (real_quantity.id_product = p.id_product AND real_quantity.id_product_attribute = 0 AND real_quantity.id_shop = '.(int)$context->shop->id.')
        WHERE product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'
            AND cp.`id_category` = '.(int)$this->id
            .($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '')
            .($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '')
            .($id_supplier ? ' AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '');

if ($random === true) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY RAND(), real_quantity.`quantity` DESC LIMIT '.(int)$random_number_products;
} else {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.(!empty($order_by_prefix) ? $order_by_prefix.'.' : '').'`'.bqSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way).', real_quantity.`quantity` DESC
    LIMIT '.(((int)$p - 1) * (int)$n).','.(int)$n;
}
```

Can anyone help/advise me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` sentence in SQL works like this:

```
ORDER BY column1, column2 /*order results by column1, if 2 rows has the same column1 value then compare by column2*/
```

This mean that in your MySQL sentence second column will never take into account because first column values (positions) are always different.

Then if you want to always order by quantity you should do something like this (asumming that `real_quantity` already has the correct quantyti value):

```
if ($random === true) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER stock.`quantity` DESC LIMIT '.(int)$random_number_products;
} else {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY stock.`quantity` DESC
    LIMIT '.(((int)$p - 1) * (int)$n).','.(int)$n;
}
```

If product with quantity 0 must appear at the end of the list, then default order won't work for you as I explain you before. If you want to keep default order but show product without stock at the end you should make 2 separate SQL statements: 1 for products with stock > 0 (using a `WHERE` condition) keeping default ordering and the other one with products without stock. Then merge results.

Good luck.

Comment: Default order must stay, and products with quantity zero appears on the end of list, with having pagination (LIMIT)

Comment: If product with quantity 0 must appear at the end of the list, then default order won't work for you as I explain you before. If you want to keep default order but show product without stock at the end you should make 2 separate SQL statements: 1 for products with stock > 0 (using a WHERE condition) keeping default ordering and the other one with products without stock. Then merge results.

Comment: I found a better way, for example `ORDER BY stock.quantity > 0 DESC, pl.name ASC` sorts first by quantity, and next by name